# Calling a void function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to call a function that will display a tetris shape on my map. The function below contains all the different tetris shapes and it need a parameter `ShapeType` in order for it to know which shape to drop. This parameter will be random but we will use `1` as an example.

```
void TetrisShapes(char ShapeType){
    if (ShapeType == 1){
        Map[0][0] = ' ';    Map[1][0] = 'X';    Map[2][0] = ' ';    Map[3][0] = ' ';
        Map[0][1] = ' ';    Map[1][1] = 'X';    Map[2][1] = ' ';    Map[3][1] = ' ';
        Map[0][2] = ' ';    Map[1][2] = 'X';    Map[2][2] = 'X';    Map[3][2] = ' ';
        Map[0][3] = ' ';    Map[1][3] = ' ';    Map[2][3] = ' ';    Map[3][3] = ' ';
    }

    if(ShapeType == 2){
        Map[0][0] = ' ';    Map[1][0] = ' ';    Map[2][0] = ' ';    Map[3][0] = ' ';
        Map[0][1] = ' ';    Map[1][1] = 'X';    Map[2][1] = 'X';    Map[3][1] = ' ';
        Map[0][2] = 'X';    Map[1][2] = 'X';    Map[2][2] = ' ';    Map[3][2] = ' ';
        Map[0][3] = ' ';    Map[1][3] = ' ';    Map[2][3] = ' ';    Map[3][3] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Once a shape is chosen, we take the shape and call it, and place it on the map with specific coordinates `ShapePosX` and `ShapePosY` as you can see below

```
Map[ShapePosX][ShapePosY] = TetrisShapes(1);
```

Now my problem is that I cannot call the above line because the function is void and does'nt return anything.. but it should return the array displaying the tetris piece in the coordinates of `ShapePosX` and `ShapePosY`.

What can I do to have the function be called in this specific problem? thanks

Comment: I would recommend reading a book on `C`. Calling a function and returning values is about the most fundamental component of functional programming there is.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you've picked the return type `void` despite you clearly wanting to return something?

Comment: Judging from the code, `Map` is a global variable defined outside the function.  The second fragment, the assignment, is also using a variable called `Map`; is that also the global variable?  On the face of it, you just need to call `TetrisShapes(1);` without any assignment, and the global variable will be initialized.  If you need to copy the material from the top of the `Map` array to somewhere else, you might most effectively pass the destination (`ShapePosX` and `ShapePosY`) to `TetrisShapes()` as extra arguments, and arrange for the code there to place the shape in the correct place.

Comment: You should be able to do a neater job than writing out 16 assignments for each different shape, too.  However, without knowing more about the data structures, it is hard to tell what's the best way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are programming in C++, you could pass the array as a parameter to the function.

So basically the prototype of your function becomes:

```
void TetrisShapes(char ShapeType, char Map[][3])
```

Then, assuming you have already declared the array Map, you would call your function as:

```
TetrisShapes(1, Map);
```